# Optional elements on XPath SQL Server

Tags: xml, xpath

I have to import xml files to to a SQL Server Database. I am using OPENXML, but since the files have two different layouts (because it was updated a couple years ago) I don't know any way to import both layouts on the same function.

My current code is like this:

```
FROM OPENXML(@idoc, N'ROOT/event1 /event2 /event3 /event4 /event5 /event6')
```

The code is working for the newer layout.

My problem is that the event3 and event4 elements on the XML only appear in files that were generated after october 2022.

Is there a way to point that those two elements are optional? Any way the funcion can "jump" from event2 to event5 if event3 and event4 does not exist?

Thank you for your attention

Comment: Note: I removed some misleading tags. This question has nothing to do with SQL or SQL Server, it is about XML/XPath. That those xml files might be used in a SQL Server DB doesn't matter to answer the question.

Comment: @JonasMetzler thank you for your corrections. I don't post questions very often so i appreciate your commentary.

Comment: Technically OPENXML is a SQL Server only function, which might have additional limitations/inputs, so i think it's reasonable to include the sql-server tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do something like this:

```sql
declare @x xml = '<ROOT><event1><event2><event3><event4><event5><event6>test</event6></event5></event4></event3></event2></event1></ROOT>'
declare @h int
exec sys.sp_xml_preparedocument @h output, @x
select *
FROM OPENXML(@h, N'ROOT/event1/event2//event5/event6')

exec sys.sp_xml_removedocument @h
```

OPENXML is a bit old-school though, you might wanna look into something newer like the nodes function.